# Angular 4 material autocomplete with firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

i can't output and filter $key object of firebase.
When loading this error appears:
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

My firebase

```
"clients" : {
    "222" : {
      ...
    },
    "1111" : {
      ...
    },
    "42423424" : {
      ...
    },
    "242342342" : {
     ...
    },
    "453533535" : {
      ...
    },
    "822233311" : {
     ...
    },
    "89510135551" : {
     ...
    },
    "89510145553" : {
     ...
    }
  }
```

My html

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="State" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="clientCtrl">
</md-input-container>
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredClient | async" [value]="state.$key">
    {{ state.$key }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

And my ts file

```
clientbase: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
clientCtrl: FormControl;
filteredClient: any;
 constructor(private af: AngularFire){
 this.clientbase = af.database.list('/clients/');

    this.clientCtrl = new FormControl();
     this.filteredClient = this.clientCtrl
                               .valueChanges
                               .startWith(null)
                               .map(name => this.filterClient(name));
}

  filterClient(val: string) {
    return val ? this.clientbase
       .map(list => list.filter(
       s =>  new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi')
       .test(s.$value)
    )) : this.clientbase;
  }
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows:

```js
  clientbase: any[];
  clientCtrl: FormControl;
  filteredClient: any;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire){
    af.database.list('/clients/')
        .subscribe(items => { this.clientbase = items; });

    this.clientCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredClient = this.clientCtrl
        .valueChanges
        .startWith(null)
        .map(name => this.filterClient(name));
  }

  filterClient(val: string) {
    return val && this.clientbase? 
           this.clientbase
               .filter(s => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(s.$value))
           :this.clientbase;
  }
```

This way it worked for me.